# why we use next() method in java?

Tags: java, ms-access, iterator

Here is the code

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\MUHAMMAD SHAHAB\\STUD1.accdb");

Statement st = conn.createStatement();
String sql="select Username,Password from SUN where Username='"+user+"'and Password='"+pass+"'";
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

int count=0;
while(rs.next()) {
    count=count+1;
}
if(count>0) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Access granted");
} else if(count<1) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User Not Found\nAccess is Denied");
}
```

I am creating a user verification system in Java and I have connected my program with MS Access. I have inserted some records in the fields of table `SUN` in MS Access and it is working properly. But I just want to know the working of  `next()` method and `count` variable in my program.

Comment: count is variable that count numbers of rows, rs.next() go to the next row in your resultset if exists. Next time use google for this, it's pretty easy question and google will find you a lot of tutorials with that.

Comment: Did you try documentation before asking question https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next() ?

Comment: `next()` gets the next row, or returns `false` is there isn't any.  `count` counts the number of rows.  The code is as simple as it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It moves (or tries to, returning a boolean telling whether it succeeded or not) the resultset cursor forward. The `count` variable is useless, since you can just write `if(rs.next())` to determine which message is shown.

Comment: it means that you are trying to say that it is basically moving cursor forward in ms access table?

Comment: No. In the resultset.

Comment: It better to assign to a Boolean variable rather than using it straightly in boolean statements. 

boolean rowExists = rs.next();

rowExists can be used in multiple places wherever you need but rs.next() can't be used since it's moving forward always.

Comment: @Gopidoss There's no "it's better to assign" rule. In this particular case, the `count` *and* the `while` are useless. It's not "better" in any way.

Comment: Agreed @Kayaman, My point is if the existence of row needs to solve multiple use cases then I would suggest to hold it in a boolean container (rowExists) rather direclty use it in 'Equality Operators' since it's moves the cursor forward one row from its current position. 
boolean rowExists = lotteryLogRs.next();

while (proceed) {
 if (rowExists) {
  //do something
 } 
........
break;
........
}
.......
.......

// Add remaining
if (rowExists) {
 //do something
}

Comment: @Gopidoss Of course then you'll have to. But in this case you don't need to, and it only makes the code more unclear.